# Ag grid angular not rendering when set height of grid 100%

Tags: ag-grid-angular, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid-angular enterprise and when I set height of grid 100% it's not rendering but if I set height in pixel like 500px I can see grid. Actually I have to show grid with all 20 rows without scrolling but only 10 rows showing and remaining 10 rows I need to scroll. I set page size 20 and I am using server side sorting and filtering. I have to make use of grid to all space of its parent element.